# NGINX: when 404, try the same URL with prefix

Tags: nginx

I would like to create a rule in my NGINX config file to add this functionality:

if:

`www.mydomain.com/*` gives out `404` I would like NGINX to redirect to `www.mydomain.com/*-obsolete`.

for example, if a user navigates to:

`www.mydomain.com/testpage` and `404` is to be returned, I'd like NGINX to redirect to `www.mydomain.com/testpage-obsolete` to try and avoid the `404`.

How is that done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri-obsolete $uri/ $uri-obsolete/ =404;
    }
```

More complex case, showing obsolete html files:

```
    location ~ ^(.*)/([^/]+)\.(html?)$ {
        set $file $1/$2;
        set $ext $3;
        try_files $file.$ext $file-obsolete.$ext =404;
    }
```