# Nginx rewrite some/url to some/url.html

Tags: nginx

I have NGINX server and I need all links http://some/url to be redirected to http://some/url.html

Those three conditions: request_uri is not empty, at the end there is no slash and the URL does not end with ".html"

I tried this:

```
server {
  ...
  rewrite ^/(.+[^/])(?!.*\.html)$ $1.html permanent;
}
```

But it does not work.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you really need to get 301/302 redirect or just open corresponding html files with such links? If so, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53732583) question.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
server {
  server_name some;
  ...
  location /url {
    try_files $uri $uri.html =404;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: I forgot to say that I have no physical links 'some/url' and 'some/url.html'. They are virtual.
Under the hood I have the Magento engine, which itself handles such links

Comment: Oh, sorry. Then you should probably look around for a Magento tutorial which tells the exact rewrite rules needed for normal running.